# Sort a c++ list and remove all duplicate strings

Tags: c++, list, sorting, duplicates

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <list>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

istream& GetLines(istream& is, list<string>& list) {
    string str;
    if (list.size() > 0) {
        list.clear();
    }
    while (getline(is, str, is.widen('\n'))) {
        list.push_back(str);
    }

    return is;
}

void Print(const list<string>& list) {
    for (auto it = list.cbegin(); it != list.cend(); it++) {
        cout << *it << endl;
    }
}

void SortAndUnique(list<string>& list) {}

int main() {
    list<string> list;
    ifstream f(
        "/home/jacksparrow/Downloads/university/project/module3/Module_3/"
        "T2-list/src  /main.cpp");

    // Read the file into list
    if (!f.is_open() || !GetLines(f, list).eof()) {
        cout << "Opening error: Error reading main.cpp" << endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    Print(list);
    cout << "---" << endl;

    // Sort and unique
    SortAndUnique(list);
    Print(list);

    cout << "---" << endl;
    // Print again
    Print(list);

    return 0;
}
```

I have got the above code in a file "main.cpp" and, I read this file "main.cpp" into a list "list list;", now what I want to do is to sort that list into alphabetical order and remove the duplicate strings. Also, this upper code is my main.cpp file in which I included (#include "list.cpp" ) file which's code is written below and does 3 functions:

1. Reads the file data into the list "getline()".
2. Prints the list Print()
3. sort that "list" into alphabetical order and, removes the duplicate strings SortAndUnique().

Comment: What is this `#include "list.cpp"` ? Don't `#include` `.cpp` files.

Comment: Sounds like a job for `std::set` rather than `std::list`

Comment: Also: Is the directory really called `...T2-list/src  /main.cpp` (with that many spaces in the directory name `src  `)?

Comment: You've probably got a decent C++ class, since it talks about `<list>` and not reinventing the wheel. Your textbook will contain the methods of `list`, and also a bit about `<algorithm>`

Comment: *I searched different forums but couldn't find any proper answer.* -- If you went straight to the documentation for [std::list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list), you would have found `sort` and `unique`.

Comment: I'm trying with sort(). why I shouldn;t include #include .cpp files? any reason?

Comment: sort() and unique() worked out for me, tysm!

Comment: @JackSparrow _"why I shouldn;t include #include .cpp? any reason?"_ - Well, by convention, `.cpp` files contains the implementations, the definitions of functions etc. These should only be present in one Translation Unit. Header files contains declarations (and definitions of classes) which can be included in many TUs. If your `.cpp` contains declarations of functions rather than definitions, then rename it to `.h`/`.hpp`. If it does indeed contain actual definitions, then compile it separately and link the object files together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to solve this is as suggested to read the documentation about the container you are using and in [`std::list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list#Operations) Operations, you'll find this list:

| Public member function | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `merge` | merges two sorted lists |
| `splice` | moves elements from another list |
| `remove` `remove_if` | removes elements satisfying specific criteria |
| `reverse` | reverses the order of the elements |
| [`unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/unique) | removes consecutive duplicate elements |
| [`sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/sort) | sorts the elements |

The linked member functions are overloaded:

`std::list::sort`:

- ```cpp
  void sort();
  ```
- ```cpp
  template< class Compare >
  void sort( Compare comp );
  ```

`std::list::unique`:

- ```cpp
  size_type unique();
  ```
- ```cpp
  template< class BinaryPredicate >
  size_type unique( BinaryPredicate p );
  ```

In your case you do not need to provide a *Compare* functor or a *BinaryPredicate* since the overloads taking no arguments already do what you want.

Comment: hi, sort() and unique() worked for me, tysm sir it means a lot!